# Android Studio - Where are the log files? "mergeDebugResources" "Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details"

Tags: android-studio

Trying to reanimate an old app project, Android Studio tells me to look at the log files (wtf, an IDE should show logs directly) for errors during mergeDebugResources and I have been searching on disk, in the IDE GUI and online for those logs for more than 2 hour now.

I found some posts suggesting solutions for the actual bugs, but I cannot find any word about where the logs actually are.

I added

> --scan --stacktrace --debug

and it still does not name the resource it has issues with. There must be a way to at least identify which resource causes the issue(s), isn't there?

Thank you!

***Edit***: Now I found a log in the directory .\app\build\outputs\logs\manifest-merger-debug-report.txt (relative to the project directory). However this file does not list any error (neither error nor fail nor except nor missing nor found is written in the log file)

Comment: Did you find a resolution @Edgar Hover